# Dynamically cast to yet unknown class in ArrayList of objects

Tags: java, android, arraylist, casting

I have an ArrayList of type Object that contains 6 objects of different classes:

```
questions = new ArrayList<>();
questions.add(new Question1());
questions.add(new Question2());
questions.add(new Question3());
questions.add(new Question4());
questions.add(new Question5());
```

Depending on questionNum variable I have to get the object's method, i.e. isAnswered() from the ArrayList.

Example of what I want:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
     questionNum = i;
     if ((Question<questionNum>)questions.get(questionNum).isAnswered())
     {
          Log.d("Answered", String.valueOf(questionNum));
     }
}
```

What I am using right now:

```
else if (questionNum == 4 &&
((Question5)questions.get(questionNum)).isAnswered())
```

Any way to make it more elegant or should I go with interfaces or inheritance (doing Android project, so the every question class already inherits Fragment)?

Comment: Do your different questions differ in functionality?

Comment: You should use interface and delegate the functionality to the appropriate class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have each Question class implement an [interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html):

```
public interface Question{
    public boolean isAnswered(); 
}

public class Question1 implements Question{
    public boolean isAnswered(){
        //implementation
    }
    //other code
}
```

Then add these as Questions to the List

```
List<Question> questions = new ArrayList<Question>();
questions.add(new Question1());
```

Then you can get the Question from the List and call the appropriate method:

```
if ( questions.get(0).isAnswered() ){

}
```

Comment: You have to do casting to (Question) interface to make it correct isAnswered() call. I do get `Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object java.util.List.get(int)' on a null object reference` when I do the if statement. Any hints on avoiding it?

Comment: Casting shouldn't be necessary if the List is parametized to the class Question. `java.lang.Object java.util.List.get(int)' on a null object reference` is the List null?

Comment: My bad, I had the list declared twice: as a field and in the code. Changed the type in the field and it works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

i see three solutions here:

**A.** Add a typecaster along with each question on ArrayList like this:

```
questions = new ArrayList<>();
questions.add(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new Question1(), "Question1")));
questions.add(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new Question2(), "Question2")));
```

Then have a `switch` statement depending on the second type argument and type cast (literally) as needed

**B.**  Have each `Question*` class have a property `type` and then use a `switch` statement (as previously) to typecast appropriately, i.e:

```
class Question1
{
    public String type = "Question1";
    // ...
}
// ...
```

**C.**  Have all `Question*` classes inherit from common `Question` superclass or implement common interface as needed, i.e:

```
class Question
{
    public String type = "Question";
    public Boolean isAnswered()
    {
        return false;
    }
    // ...
}

class Question1 extends Question
{
    public String type = "Question1";
    public Boolean isAnswered()
    {
        // ..
    }
    // ...
}
// ..
```